# What is the best workaround for using data-tables in angular material 2/4?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working on an application with angular 4 and angular material already implemented but the data-table module is still in development (and appearantly will be for a while).

https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#

Do you know any solutions for implementing a data table or somethign similar in angular 4? like using the list module, maybe the grid list with a little tweak?

Or should I just use a different library for the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to start looking at other libraries for solutions, until the Material data table is ready. At that point, you can look at their design and decide for yourself if you want to migrate back to it.

From my experience, the Angular Material components are very good, high quality componets, but they take a while to get released and waiting for them eagerly with a pressing deadline is a sure way to frustration.

(Note that I'm also in your boat of waiting for the Material data table, although in my case, I can afford to wait... for now.)

You can look at ngx-datatable from swimlane, and ag-grid as two possible replacements, and I'm sure there are a few others. I don't have enough experience with either to recommend them, but I've run into both projects in my research for a datatable to use now, and the feedback has been mostly positive.

Finally, as a last alternative, you can do what I did. In my case, I just needed the visuals, so i coded up a simple `<table>` and grabbed the css from the Angular Material 1 project as a quick work-around. You won't get fancy features at all, but you can at least get the look (if not the feel).

Comment: Great I'm also waiting and not in a hurry at all since it's a hobbie so this answer is very helpful, thanks